# Несколько внешних ip для Cisco ASA

Tags: nat, cisco

Имеется подсеть от провайдера - 10.20.30.104/29.Соответственно диапазон доступных ip 106-110.Физически мне приходит один линк в виде оптики через медиаконвертер.Сейчас стоит на входе обычный свитч,за ним стоят два маршрутизатора с разными подсетями(192.168.0.0 и 192.168.100.0) и выходом в мир с разных ip (106 и 107).Сети специально разделены,одна для офиса другая гостевая.Смогу ли я с помощью ASA"ы заменить те два маршрутизатора и настроить нат с двумя внешними ip для подсетей,чтоб как и прежде , каждая выходила в мир под своим адресом?Обязателен ли для этого свитч?

Answer (score 0):

Если переформулировать твою задачу в виде «Позволит ли Cisco ASA пользователям двух изолированных сетей с приватной адресацией выходить в интернет (и каждая сеть — со своим публичным адресом)?», то ответ конечно же будет «Да, позволит».

Это я к тому, что если взять твой оригинальный вопрос — «Можной ли ASA'ой заменить маршрутизатор[ы]», то ответ будет «Нет», поскольку Cisco ASA не совсем (мягко говоря) маршрутизатор. А если не смягчать, то она совсем не маршрутизатор :)